# How do I make a macro that will add a new row with a button that will move when another new row is added

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a table that starts with one row (B14:H14) that has a button in B15 that will run a macro to insert a new row (and copy and paste the formulas from the initial row to the new row). BUT I also want to add a button in column A that will delete the row the button is in. I've run into a few problems with the button placement, I went about it two different ways.

1) Either I insert the new row at the bottom of the table and I can't place the button relative to the new row, as the Top and Left position will always be different, or

2) (this is how I have the code right now) I insert the row at the top of the table and I put the button in A14 every time. This works the first time the macro runs, but then when I run it again, the first button that was added gets stretched. The button for the second row end up with the top of it in A14, and the bottom in A15.

The code inserts the new row fine, but how do I get the button to move down when another new row is added?

Also, I'm a total n00b. Here's my code.

```
Sub Add()
'
' Add Macro
'
Rows("14:14").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("B15:H15").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B14").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(0, 207, 57.65, 14.598).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.OnAction = "Remove"
Selection.Characters.Text = "Remove"
With Selection.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=6).Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .FontStyle = "Regular"
    .Size = 11
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ColorIndex = 1
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar but instead of creating a new button for each row, I just had the one button move to which ever row was selected.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    set_selected_row Target
End Sub

Sub set_selected_row(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = shtList.ListObjects("tblList")

    Dim r, c, t
    r = tbl.Range.Rows.Count + 1
    c = tbl.Range.Columns.Count

    If Target.Row < r And Target.Column <= c Then
        Dim btnRemoveItem As Shape
        Set btnRemoveItem = shtList.Shapes("btnRemoveItem")

        t = ((Target.Row - 1) * 15)

        btnRemoveItem.Top = t
    End If
End Sub

Sub remove_item()
    Dim answer As Integer
    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to remove this item?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Remove Item")

    Dim btnRemoveItem As Shape
    Set btnRemoveItem = shtList.Shapes("btnRemoveItem")

    Dim SelectedRow
    SelectedRow = (btnRemoveItem.Top / 15) + 1

    If answer = vbYes Then
        Dim tbl As ListObject
        Set tbl = shtList.ListObjects("tblList")

        tbl.ListRows(SelectedRow - 1).Delete

        tr = tbl.Range.Rows.Count
        tc = tbl.Range.Columns.Count

        If SelectedRow > tr Then
            ar = ActiveCell.Row
            ac = ActiveCell.Column

            If ar > tr Or ac > tc Then     'check if the active cell is in the table.
                nr = ar
                nc = ac

                If nr > tr Then nr = tr
                If nc > tc Then nc = tc

                shtList.Cells(nr, nc).Select
                shtList.Cells(ar, ac).Select
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If you do it like this, then you will not have hundreds or even thousands of buttons slowing down your program.

[image]

If you want to do it this way, you need to place this code in the sheet that has the list (VBAProject > Microsoft Excel Objects > [SHEET]) and you would need to change a few of the values to work with your project, but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: can you do this without any table? I want to remove list object from the code plus named tables. Just do it on a normal sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a button, you might consider formatting a cell to look like a button and use the cell's Selection_Change or Double-Click event to trigger your macro when the cell is clicked or double-clicked.
If you opt for the single click solution you should control the Enter behaviour for the surrounding cells. This is to avoid Excel moving the cursor to such a cell automatically. use `Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlToRight`